# Center a div in a horizontal scrolling site

Tags: jquery, html, css, center

Wonder if anyone could advise on the best way to center a div in the middle of the screen of a horizontal scrolling site.

I want the header to stay positioned in the center of the screen but the rest of the site scrolls.  usually I'd just set left and right margins to zero, but as the width is set to the full scroll width I imagine I'll need to do some jQuery trickery to find the window width first of all?

Any advice very gratefully received!

Comment: "usually i'd just set left and right margins to zero" - surely you mean to `auto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done with CSS, no need for javaScript.

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header"></div>
</div>

.page{
    width:2000px;
    height:500px;
}
.header{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px; /* negative half the width */

}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ZEcax/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [Center 2.0](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/center/) plugin. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Cheers Aron, i'll check it out

Comment: This center's in the middle of the page rather than the viewport, which isn't want I want.  Cheers though.

Comment: to make it clearer - to allow the horizontal scrolling function the page width is set to over 10,000 pics wide, I want the div to centre in the viewport, not the page.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That's easy enough.

CSS:

```
 #center {
    position: fixed;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#center').css({
    'top': $(window).height()/2,
    'left': $(window).width()/2,
    'margin-left': $('#modal').width/2,
    'margin-top': $('#modal').height()/2
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="center">
    <!-- content goes here -->
</div>
```